# How to read in multiple data tables into R using apply function?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, read.table

I am relatively new to R and I'm having a problem reading in multiple tables from a directory using an apply function. What I would like to have the function do is to use a vector with paths to tables that I'm interested in and generate a list with objects consisting of each data frame corresponding the paths in that file. I've written the following code:

```
f<- function(directory){
    file.list <<- list.files(directory)
    file.paths <<- as.vector(paste(directory, file.list, sep = "/"))
    tables <- lapply(X = file.paths, FUN = read.table, header = TRUE,sep = "\t" ))
}
```

By my understanding, what I'm doing is creating a list of file names in the directory that I want, creating a path to those files, and  (where I'm failing is) looping over those paths and importing the tables they correspond to for the whole file.paths object and generating a list with those tables. I receive the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no lines available in input
```

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: This may happen if your data is empty... as in no rows of data

Comment: Your function looks OK, but don't you want it to return `tables`?

Comment: Yes - sorry that part isn't written in, just thought I would fix the error first since it means it can't create tables to begin with

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in 
    `tables <- ...`
two closing parenthesis?
try:
`tables <-    lapply(file.paths,function(x)read.table(x,header=TRUE,sep="\t"))`

Answer (score 12):

Here are a few options depending on what you want the output to be:

**A list of data frames**

```
# Load library
  library(data.table)

# Get a List of all files named with a key word, say all `.csv` files
  filenames <- list.files("C:/your/folder", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

# Load data sets
  list.DFs <- lapply(filenames,fread)
```

I'm assuming your data files are saved in `.csv` format. Note that `fread` is equivalent to `read.table` but much much faster

**Bind multiple data frames into one single data frame**

```
# Get a List of all files named with a key word, say all `.csv` files
  filenames <- list.files("C:/your/folder", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

 # Load and bind all data sets
   data <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread))
```

**Load multiple data frames as different objects to Global Environment**

```
# Get a List of DF in the directory
  filenames <- list.files("C:/your/folder", pattern="*.Rda", full.names=TRUE)

# Load data sets
  lapply(filenames, load, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘az_wac_S000_JT00_2004.csv.gz’ has magic number 'w_geo'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your file. Note that your file extension is `.gz` and not `.csv`

Comment: R can be used to read gzipped files, you just have to put a wrapper on it, like so: read.table(gzfile(az_wac_S000_JT00_2004.csv.gz)

Comment: If you want to read a bunch of zipped `.csv` files, than you're looking for a slightly different question and solution . I would suggest you post another question, or search for the solution here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/717

Comment: I have done so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459779/how-do-i-use-lapply-to-load-files-into-the-global-environment