# rbind all dataframes of a folder to one dataframe

Tags: r

How can I rbind all .RData dataframes which are stored in the same folder with identical column structure?
I tried:

```
my_list <- list.files(my_path, full.names=TRUE)
my_files <- lapply(my_list, load, envir=.GlobalEnv)
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(my_files, .id = "column_label")
```

Comment: what is the issue or the error message? it would also be convenient to provide at least 2-3 example structures of your dataframes. Just the head or the columns and data types.

Comment: Hello :) have you tryied ideas mentionned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841176/10264278)?

Comment: The error message is: Error: "Argument 1 must have names"

Comment: @ Paul: when I try ```data <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread))``` I get: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  embedded nul in string: '˜ïÚ>ùî\f ¾§\0177t.pÈô\016\002ºÔØ!_.zÝ3Ã\037\016\036¿<Kû\024§\001õm2ü±`\002PŸ~ßgß, ¾zúÓ“\034¬žù°¼òêqPZ{ãë¡þ\030‡ì€ ¹žM\016e—>\024ägº:Øñ}9ôÃ|«ƒbºÿ›°«\027HU\017÷—\\àÃG»§\024:Øx7'TW½upÚ±€#Å‘ÇAe§JM\034ƒ¥ƒ²Kß†G²¼\016\022R‚k\031-\003ìŸê\034j!+\0Ô÷rR\016«ŸƒÝŽ"ïoÍO\034œž®9q¨d‹ƒ\\\030»KcÊN ¾9¿ÄÅjúXVny\\mÿT—c\025_Ót\aÐÓzÝ\033Íì¿­_»½ºBÔÁašîƒ:=+\aï\035i_X—š;\b9Ü9slã.û¯Êâ§\016ô1“ª\036î¯–©Ý\035©SÖ“EÏb*%‡î\flZE+\032è/\001pÁ\003I¡Œ†ÃŸ\001‹Éù\016\f'

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
lapply(my_files, load, .GlobalEnv)
df <- do.call(rbind, mget(sub('\\.RData', '', basename(my_files))))
```

Comment: Thank you. When I run this I get  a matrix with only one column which contains the names of the files.
       [,1]                            
  [1,] "CLC_1_all_300"                 
  [2,] "CLC_10_all_300"                
  [3,] "CLC_100_all_300"               
  [4,] "CLC_102_all_300"               
  [5,] "CLC_106_all_300"               
  [6,] "CLC_107_all_300"               
  [7,] "CLC_109_all_300"

Comment: Thank you. There seem to be a conflict with the names of the saved RData dataframes.

Comment: @user13472708 I am not sure if I understand. It worked for me on small subset of  `.RData` files that I had. Did it work for you?

Comment: Thank you. There seems to be a conflict with the names of the saved RData-dataframes. I had renamed the filenames, but the files which are loaded into the global environment still have the old names.  I tried:
 ```my_list <- list.files(my_path, full.names=TRUE)
my_files <- lapply(my_list, load, envir=.GlobalEnv)
df <- do.call(rbind, mget(sub('\\.RData', '', basename(my_files))))```
but a file was not found.

Comment: Are `my_files` all unique? Or they have some overlapping names?